# Golang Как срез получает следующий элемент массива если он хранит ссылку только на первый?

Tags: golang

Не совсем понимаю, везде написано, что срезы хранят ссылку именно на первый элемент массива, но как тогда он может получить значение второго элемента и т.д.?

Comment: Вы почему-то забыли про то, что срез хранит в себе количество элементов

Answer (score 3):

Срез внутри устроен как [структура данных из трёх полей](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#SliceHeader):

- Data указатель на данные,
- Len число элементов,
- Cap максимальное количество элементов, которые может вместить срез без переаллокации.

Элементы хранятся в срезе один за другим, без просветов. Поэтому найти второй элемент среза типа `[]T` совсем несложно:

- убедиться, что в срезе есть второй элемент: `Len > 1`
- прибавить размер `T` к указателю `Data` - так получен указатель на второй элемент
- вернуть объект, который лежит по полученному указателю.

Размер типа `T` знает компилятор.

Answer (score 0):

Спецификация типа для среза - это []T, где T - тип элементов среза. В отличие от типа массива, тип среза не имеет заданной длины.
Нулевое значение среза равно nil.
Для добавления элемента необходимо прибавить []T к (указатель) Data. Следовательно мы можем узнать о любых других элементах среза.